# Some WordPress Posts are automatically becoming comments on other Posts

Tags: plugins, comments

This seems like a weird issue. I have published multiple posts on one of my websites. Sometimes, another post on my website (Post C) appears as comment under some other post (Post A).

The content of the comment on (Post A) will be some content of (Post C) surrounded by ellipsis. The author of the comment is mentioned as the title of Post C and it links back to Post C.

The IP addresses for the comments may or may not be different. Most of them are from Texas, USA.

The gravatar of the comment seems to link to an image trackback.png.

How can I stop these comments from appearing on the website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called pingback. Whenever you link another post, that post will be notified as a comment.

I personally don't like this feature. You can disable it in Settings > Discussion > untick "Allow link notifications from other blogs".

I think this setting will only apply to new posts, so you also need to disable them using Quick Edit. In your post list > tick all posts > bulk action edit > set Pings to "Do not allow"

Comment: Thanks @hrsetyono. :) I thought pingbacks only happen among posts on different websites and not within posts on same website.

This is not a security issue, right? I was afraid my site has been hacked.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a security issue or not. I have been disabling this for all my sites since long time ago.